# How to spark-submit a Play Framework Project

Tags: scala, apache-spark, program-entry-point, playback, spark-submit

I am working with Play2 Framework, (2.5.18) and Spark(2.3.0), Spark-Cassandra connector (2.3.0) and sbt 0.13.15
I am using Play framework to design an API, using Spark Cassandra Connector from Datastax to access data. 
I would like to know how to do a spark-job with spark-submit since Play has no main class for the spark-submit parameters

Thank you for your help

Comment: if you want to run Spark job by REST you should use Apache livy or Spark job server

Comment: Hi, thanks you for your answer. but the thing is livy also need a "className" in their parameters, do you know if there is a main class in Play Framework I can use ?